# Restoring a single TFS project from backup

Tags: tfs

Ok. So I have accidentally deleted one of my team projects from TFS (GIT) using TFSDeleteProject. Fortunately, I have a daily backup lying around. I want to restore only that particular project without impacting others. Is there a way to go about doing that in the safest possible way?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

The only supported restore scenario is a team project collection restore. You can't restore only one project out of a team project collection.